# Determine Spark UI port from within Jupyter/pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm running multiple Jupyter notebooks each with their own pyspark (Spark 1.6.1) kernel. How can I discover which Spark UI instance belongs to which kernel? Obviously, I could just cycle through the open pages (http://sparky:4040, http://sparky:4041, etc) and try to work it out, but I hope there's a programmatical way of doing it.

Edit: I don't have root access to the servers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is ugly, but it works...

```
import urllib
sparkHost = "sparky"

for x in range(4040,4060):
    link = "http://"+sparkHost+":"+str(x)+"/environment/"
    try:
        f = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
        myfile = f.read()
        if (sc.applicationId in str(myfile)):
            print ('Application ID found on port ', x)
    except:
        pass
```

Any improvements on this are more than welcome!

Comment: If someone else is also running spark on the same machine, you will get all those ports too. Also, if the port number is beyond 4060, it would not work. It is going to be very slow. Instead, use sc.uiWebUrl Check here for more details https://discuss.cloudxlab.com/t/how-do-i-access-the-webui-from-jupyter/1990

Answer (score 5):

If `sc` is your spark context, you can run:

```py
sc.uiWebUrl.split(':')[-1]
```

Comment: Great! Or if you have only defined `SparkSession`, you can get the UI address with `spark.conf.get("spark.driver.memory")` where `spark` is an instance of `SparkSession`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nmap` utility for this:

```
sudo nmap -O sparky
```

It'll show all open ports at sparky host.

Comment: That would definitely find out all of the active UI ports, but not which port was active for which kernel. Also, I don't have root access to the server :(

Answer (score 0):

When you start the spark using either pyspark or spark-shell, it starts spark ui at a port. This port is by default 4040 but if it is busy it tries 4041. And then 4042 and so on. When you run spark-shell or pyspark from console it prints on the screen

But if you are using Spark from Jupyter which is also called Apache Toree, then it doesn’t print anything on the screen.

So, to access the Spark UI URl, you will have to run the following command in the Jupyter scala notebook: sc.uiWebUrl

To run something in notebook, type something in the box and press shift+enter.

Also, please note that, it prints the local host name. You would need to find the right hostname in CloudxLab’s “IP Mappings” tab.

For more detailed answer please check here: https://discuss.cloudxlab.com/t/how-do-i-access-the-webui-from-jupyter/1990

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.